# Webpack: ERROR in ./src/index.tsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '...'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ts-loader, tsx

I have the following error when trying to serve my app using webpack-dev-server:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 
'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-resources-boilerplate\src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 15:28-44
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.tsx
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Here is my index.tsx file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const root = document.querySelector('#root')
render(<App />, root)
```

Help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What is your file structure like? Are you sure your App file is in the same directory as the index file?

Comment: Yes it is in the src directory as well.

Comment: If I set the App component in ./src/components I get the following error:
    `ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/App' in 
    'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-resources-boilerplate\src'
     @ ./src/index.tsx 15:28-55
     @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.tsx`

Answer (score 14):

Add the following to your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    // existing code goes here
    // ...

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
};
```

More info in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions).

Comment: this did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what was happening is that react-scripts webpack config file was not finding my tsconfig file because it was named:

> .tsconfig.json

instead of

> tsconfig.json